# Kotlin Native equivalent of System.exit(-1)

Tags: java, kotlin, native, kotlin-native

In the following Kotlin/JVM program `System.exit(-1)` stops the execution of the program with an error exit code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    if (args.size < 2) {
        println("too few args!")
        System.exit(-1)
    }
    println("Hello, ${args[1]} from ${args[0]}")
}
```

Kotlin/Native does not have access to any Java classes, including `System`. So what would the equivalent function be for a Kotlin/Native program to stop execution of the program with an error code?

Comment: I guess you could normal `exit` function from C.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `exitProcess`:

```
import kotlin.system.exitProcess
...
exitProcess(exitCode)
```

[Declaration and documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/system/Process.kt#L19) in the Kotlin source code.

Comment: Hmm, this is not available in commonMain. Is there an import missing?
The docs link is also broken.

Comment: @milosmns [Should still be valid](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/42af684ab7c4de3d337345a69de6c9356d77c5f9/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/cpp/Natives.cpp#L106-L108). Not sure though, haven't  used Kotlin in a couple years

Comment: I found the new link (repo was moved), updating now. But still didn't work for me, it's not resolving the `system` package :/